# What is the definition of finite graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Some books say it's a graph with finite order(which means V is finite) and some other books say that it's with finite V and finite E.
Could you let me know which one is right?

Comment: Probably the more common definition is a graph having finite $V$ and finite $E$. However, authors are allowed to use their own definitions for things, so be sure to check the definition whenever you read a new text. What one author defines might not mean the same thing as another's definition.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this depends on the author to some extent, but almost universally the intent is for everything to be finite. The difference in the definition of a finite graph comes down to the difference in definition of a graph. Thus, in the two most notable textbooks on graph theory:

- In Diestel's *Graph Theory*, a graph is a simple graph: $E$ is a subset of $[V]^2$, the set of $2$-element subsets of $E$. Here, it is impossible to have a finite vertex set and an infinite edge set, so the definition of a finite graph is one in which $V$ is finite.
- In West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, a graph is by default a multigraph: $E$ is an arbitrary set, and there is a relation that associates to each edge in $E$ two vertices called its endpoints. Here, $V$ and $E$ can be finite or infinite independently, so the definition of a finite graph is one in which $V$ and $E$ are both finite.

It is very rare to consider a multigraph with a finite vertex set and an infinite edge set, so nobody goes to any special effort to make sure their definitions are consistent in such a situation. But such graphs ought to be treated as infinite graphs, because they would otherwise be at least a little bit of an exception to many discussions of finite graphs: just to give one example, they don't have real-valued adjacency matrices.

Comment: Well said. I thought the most notable textbook on Graph Theory was Harary.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that one's too old for me. If we go back too far, the textbooks are no good for terminology, because they start talking about points and lines instead of vertices and edges.